# Laptop In-built monitor is not recognized. (Nvidia 3060 & AMD integrated)

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

When I install ubuntu(dual boot) without selecting install third-party apps, the laptop monitor works okay but in display settings, it shows 'unclaimed device'. Also here if I run the command 'sudo apt upgrade' the laptop monitor stops working(shows laptop brand) and only the external monitor works. If I install ubuntu with third part apps selected, my external monitor works but without detecting my inbuilt display.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 , Lenovo Legion 5 Gen 6  , Nvidia RTX 3060

What should I do to make it work? Also please advise me how to change from UEFI to UEFI/BIOS

Comment: It's not very clear what you are describing. Be sure to include not just commands but the full unredacted output of each command. Please use the formatting tools in your post to render anything in your terminal in monospace font: put three backticks on the line before and the line after any blocks of code.  Proofread your question and make sure it is devoid of ambiguity. People who aren't looking at your device need to understand the problem based on your description. As an example "laptop monitor stops working shows laptop brand" is ambiguous. Give better descriptions or upload photos

Comment: It's not clear why you are running `sudo apt upgrade` in the first place nor is it clear what happens when you run this command. Remember that you must always run `sudo apt update` to get the list of available software before performing any other tasks in `apt`.  It's also ambiguous when you say "it shows unclaimed device".  Where are you seeing this?  As a result of what?